# EF relationship based on FK to compound PK

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following tables:

- Sales (ID, ...)
- Products (ID, ...)
- ProductSales (ProductID, SaleID, ...)

Basically Sales are organized at a particular dates and products can be on sale (possibility at multiple Sales simultaneously).

Now when a user adds a product to their cart, I record the product ID and the sale ID.

- CartItems (ProductID, SaleID, ...)

So a CartItem points to a Product as well as to a Sale. But since (ProductID, SaleID) is the primary key of ProductSales, it could also be said that the CartItem points to a ProductSale.

Can this relationship (accessing the ProductSale) be mapped in Entity Framework (v5, Database First)?

Comment: you mean multiple foreign key on same table?

Comment: If you're going `database-first`, try to open the Designer, create from database, check the resulting model and see if you like the results.

Comment: I have done this but the designer creates a relationship to Products, another to Sales but not to ProductSales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out. The association won't be created automatically when you update the model from the database but it can be added manually.

- Right-click the designer and choose *Add association*.
- On the left hand side choose the *CartItem* entity with a multiplicity of *Many*, on the left hand side choose the *ProductSale* entity with a multiplicity of *1*. Name the navigation properties as you wish.
- Select the association in the designer and go to its properties.
- In *Referential Constraint*, set the *Principal* to *ProductSale* and set the *Dependent* to *CartItem*. In the key mapping below, map *SaleID* to *SaleID* and *ProductID* to *ProductID*.